# call a different controller's method in menu.html in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 1.My menu.html has something like this:

```
<ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
  Login
</ion-item>
```

And this login() method is in AppCtrl.
What I want is that I shift this login method to a LoginCtrl which will not have a login.html(as I am only providing google login) and directly do google login. So how do I do something like this:

```
menu.html:

<ion-item menu-close ng-click="LoginCtrl.login()">
  Login
</ion-item>

login.js:

angular.module('login', [])
.controller('loginController', function($scope) {
  var vm=this;
  vm.login = function(){
    console.log("click");
  }
});

app.js

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('app', {
   url: '/app',
   abstract: true,
   templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
   controller: 'AppController',
   controllerAs: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.playlists', {
   url: '/playlists',
   views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
      controller: 'PlaylistsController',
      controllerAs: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
    }
   }
  })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/playlists');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try `$parent`.
you can access the parent scope as follows

```
//This assigns the RESULT of login() to $scope.test
$scope.test= $scope.$parent.login();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I believe you need to assign `var vm = $scope.LoginCtrl = this`. This is so the ng-click has the correct method to fire, as it currently isn't assigned to the login function.

Comment: It's hard to debug your problem without more information, is this all the code @jarvis?

Comment: Hey I have edited my question and added some more info as well!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the controllerAs syntax to give an alias to each controller. You can then call any method as follows:

```
alias.method()
```

The method you are calling must be in scope. e.g. where a controller is nested in another, the child controller has access to the parents methods.

Comment: My problem is that I need to call child controller's method from parent and for this the above method is not working!!!